# Using a loop to perform the autofill in all the columns in the range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code working as expected. I am looking to simplify the autofill done in the last part, which would look cleaner using a loop through all the columns in the H:N range.

But I'm having trouble getting the logic behind how the loop should work.

Any advices ?

Thank you all in advance !

```
Sub test()

Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
Dim targetWS As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long

Set sourceWS = Sheets("xml data")
Set targetWS = Sheets("Expiries")

sourceWS.Activate
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


' Clean data in source worksheet
sourceWS.Range("F2:G" & LastRow).ClearContents
sourceWS.Range("H3:N" & LastRow).ClearContents

' Copy crew code and course from xml data
sourceWS.Range("A2:B" & LastRow).Copy
sourceWS.Range("F2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
' Extend formulas in column H to N

sourceWS.Range("H2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & LastRow)
sourceWS.Range("I2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & LastRow)
sourceWS.Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
sourceWS.Range("K2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K" & LastRow)
sourceWS.Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & LastRow)
sourceWS.Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
sourceWS.Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:N" & LastRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: For myChar =Asc("H)" to Asc("N"), then  'sourceWS.Range("chr(myChar) &"2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Chr(mychar)"2:" & chr(myChar) & LastRow)

Comment: I am getting a compile error, with an expected list separator. The "to" seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: Asc("H") not Asc("H)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Autofill Formulas Without AutoFill

- No need for `AutoFill` and especially no need for a loop.
- Remember that loops slow down the code and should be avoided whenever possible.

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    'Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = Sheets("Expiries") ' never used?
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheets("xml data")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Range("A" & sws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Clean data in source worksheet
    sws.Range("F2:G" & slRow).ClearContents
    sws.Range("H3:N" & slRow).ClearContents ' keep first row of formulas
    
    ' Copy crew code and course from xml data
    ' (more efficient and doesn't mess up the selection like 'PasteSpecial')
    With sws.Range("A2:B" & slRow)
        sws.Range("F2").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    
    ' Extend formulas in column H to N
    ' (more efficient than 'AutoFill')
    sws.Range("H2:N" & slRow).Formula = sws.Range("H2:N2").Formula
    ' If you insist:
    'sws.Range("H2:N2").AutoFill Destination:=sws.Range("H2:N" & slRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It is working as expected. And thank you for schooling me :)

Comment: N.B Sheets ("Expiries") is used but not in that part of the code. I only posted the part for which I had a question.